# Kubernetes : error validating data: found invalid field env for v1.PodSpec;

Tags: yaml, kubernetes

I am using below yaml file to create the pod, kubectl command giving below error.

How to correct this error message?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: command-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-command
spec:
  containers:
  - name: command-demo-container
    image: debian
    command: ["printenv"]
    args: ["HOSTNAME", "KUBERNETES_PORT"]
  env:
  - name: MESSAGE
    value: "hello world"
    command: ["/bin/echo"]
    args: ["$(MESSAGE)"]

kubectl create -f commands.yaml
error: error validating "commands.yaml": error validating data: found invalid field env for v1.PodSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

follow example from this page.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/define-command-argument-container/

Thanks
-SR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your—syntactically correct—YAML results in an incorrect data-structure for kubernetes. In YAML the indentations can affect the structure of the data. See [this](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/troubleshooting/yaml_idiosyncrasies.html).

I think this should be correct:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: command-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-command
spec:
  containers:
  - name: command-demo-container
    image: debian
    command: ["printenv"]
    args: ["HOSTNAME", "KUBERNETES_PORT"]
    env:
    - name: MESSAGE
      value: "hello world"
    command: ["/bin/echo"]
    args: ["$(MESSAGE)"]
```